# Selenium inconsistent in finding login fields in iframe

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, iframe, webdriverwait

I am webscraping stats from https://game-rainbow6.ubi.com/en-us/uplay/player-statistics/dbd1cef3-d69d-4296-a235-ae8d7d70363f/multiplayer. And I am using Selenium and python to log in and scrape the stats I want. The login process all happens in a class called player

The webdriver needs to find two fields "AuthEmail" and "AuthPassword". My problem is that sometimes it finds the fields and logs in properly but other times throws the error that it can not find the fields. I have tired an implicit wait thinking it needed the ifram to load fully, but I still get the error sometimes. I also tried an explicit wait with:

```
WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "AuthEmail"))
```

but I get the error that my:

```
__init__ function takes 2 args and I gave it 3
```

Code trials:

```
def __init__(self, player_name):
    self.driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    self.player_stats = {}
def login(self):

        #login pop up is in a different IFrame, switch to it
    iframe = self.driver.find_element_by_tag_name('iframe')
    self.driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)

    login_email = self.driver.find_element_by_id('AuthEmail')
    login_email.send_keys('')
    login_pwd = self.driver.find_element_by_id('AuthPassword')
    login_pwd.send_keys('')
    submit_button = self.driver.find_element_by_id('LogInButton')
    submit_button.click()

    #Switch driver back to main webpage for webscraping
    self.driver.switch_to.default_content()
```

Comment: How can webdriver find two fields "AuthEmail" and "AuthPassword" unless you click the element with text as **LOG IN**?

Comment: if you have a ubisoft account the site brings up the login iframe automatically, I used to have it click the login button but that was unnneccesary

Comment: None other then the _ubisoft account holders_ can access the relevant HTML. So you need to update the question with the relevant HTML.

Comment: I changed it to a more relevant link. it is inconsistent on whether or not it finds the login fields

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The desired elements are within an `<iframe>` so you have to:

- Induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired *frame to be available and switch to it*.
- Induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired *element to be clickable*.
- You can use the following solution:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

  options = Options()
  options.add_argument("start-maximized")
  options.add_argument("disable-infobars")
  options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options, executable_path=r'C:\Utility\BrowserDrivers\chromedriver.exe')
  driver.get("https://game-rainbow6.ubi.com/en-us/uplay/player-statistics/dbd1cef3-d69d-4296-a235-ae8d7d70363f/multiplayer")
  WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"iframe.ng-scope.ng-isolate-scope.rs-template-uplay-connect")))
  WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input.form-control#AuthEmail"))).send_keys("DMatza")
  driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input.form-control#AuthPassword").send_keys("DMatza")
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: ubisoft]